# Can't get a tftp server working on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: tftp, ubuntu-22.04

I had tftpf-hpa working on my Ubuntu server to send/receive images and configs from my Cisco devices.

Today it is not working.  The service won't start, even if I try it manually.  It does not tell me why it won't start.  If I run the start-stop-daemon with strace I get a lot of output, but I cannot see what the problem is.

I tried switching to atftpd, but that core dumps when it tries to write a file that I have sent from a cisco switch ... something I do quite often and has always worked before.

I also tried to use the tftpd package, but syslog indicates that it is trying to send the file I have asked the switch to send, rather than receive it.  The switch indicates "Permission denied" as the problem.  To test with tftpd, I changed ownership on /var/lib/tftboot and all its contents to nobody:nogroup.

I installed tftpd-hpa on another server running Ubuntu 20.04 and that is working.  So I am not dead in the water, but that is a secondary server.

Can anyone help me get a working tftp server on my primary Ubuntu server?  If there is a way to troubleshoot these problems, please let me know.

Comment: Seen similar, and in that case systemd was messed up (blocking udp 69 in its own process)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what was wrong and now I have a working tftp server once again.

I disabled ipv6 on this server recently, and when that is done, tftpd-hpa requires adding the --ipv4 option so it does not try to bind to ipv6, which fails.  Didn't run into this with any other software ... most software simply logs a warning saying it couldn't bind to ipv6.

These are the options I now have in /etc/default/tftpd-hpa:

TFTP_OPTIONS="--secure --ipv4 --create --permissive --umask 027"